# Deploying to 80 site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, solution-package

I am on a project that has 80 site collections.  I successfully implemented a few solutions with Vue.js on 1 of the site collections and now I need to implement on the other 79 site collections.  How can I deploy the solution to all the site collections?

For example, I created a global top navigation that gets the menu from a SharePoint list.

Please provide steps or resources on how to do this from the ground up.  I have never deployed a solution before, so I'm not even sure how to prepare the solution or deploy.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could deploy the solution in the farm.

If you want to deply the solution to all web applications, use this:

```
Add-SPSolution "D:\SharePointSolution.wsp"
Install-SPSolution –Identity SharePointSolution.wsp -AllWebApplications –GACDeployment
```

If you just want to deply the solution to single web application, try this:

```
Add-SPSolution "D:\SharePointSolution.wsp"
Install-SPSolution –Identity SharePointSolution.wsp –WebApplication http://sp –GACDeployment
```

You could go to CA-> System Settings-> Manage Farm solutions to check the solution.

Then go to the site collection features or site features to activate this feature.

Reference:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/install-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps